# Which shortcut in Zsh does the same as Ctrl-U in Bash?

Tags: bash, zsh

In Bash, when I am typing a command, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, all characters from the beginning of the line to the cursor are going to be removed. However, in zsh, if I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, the whole line is gone.

How to do the same in Zsh as in Bash?

Comment: Actually, this is an Emacs hotkey, not bash. Bash reuses lots of the Emacs key bindings. Some other Emacs key bindings to zsh: https://code.google.com/p/vinipsmaker/source/browse/config/.zshrc?spec=svn846ef53b90527aaab08418755be911b81d4c8552&r=846ef53b90527aaab08418755be911b81d4c8552#78

Answer (score 152, accepted):

It sounds like you'd like for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to be bound to `backward-kill-line` rather than `kill-whole-line`, so add this to your `.zshrc`:

```
bindkey \^U backward-kill-line
```

The `bindkey` builtin and the available editing commands (“widgets”) are documented in the `zshzle` man page.

Comment: Zsh doesn't use readline, instead it uses its own zle. So i am gonna customize the keybind. thanks!

Comment: put this in your $HOME/.zshrc and you should be set after you either run "source $HOME/.zshrc" or you open a new terminal session/window

Comment: ```bindkey | grep backward-kill-line```
should output
```"^U" backward-kill-line```

Comment: Doesn't work for me : It kills the whole line :(

Comment: @yPhil After adding `bindkey \^U backward-kill-line` to your `~/.zshrc`,  open a new terminal window or run "source $HOME/.zshrc" to make your change work~ It works for me.