# How to delete from current position to the beginning of the line?

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

How do I delete everything from my cursor current position to the beginning of the line?

For example, say I'm running `npm run start` and my cursor is positioned just before `start`? How do I remove `npm run`  with a keyboard shortcut leaving `start`?

```
~ npm run █start
```

I'm expecting something like how <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> deletes the last word. Similarly, is there a shortcut to delete from current cursor position to the beginning of the line?

I'm using oh-my-zsh shell on Mac 10.12.

EDIT:
Some shortcuts here -

```
move to the start of line - ctrl + a
move to the end of line - ctrl + e 
clear the word previous to the cursor - ctrl + w
clear text from cursor to the start of line - ctrl + r, by adding "bindkey \^R backward-kill-line" to your zshrc file 
clear text from cursor to the end of line - ctrl + k
clear full line - ctrl + u
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which shortcut in Zsh does the same as Ctrl-U in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483604/which-shortcut-in-zsh-does-the-same-as-ctrl-u-in-bash)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[Use Ctrl+U](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

> unix-line-discard (C-u)
>       Kill backward from point to the beginning of the line. The killed text is saved on the kill-ring.

It is also useful to see `man bash`.

In case you use zsh, you should add this line: `bindkey \^U backward-kill-line` to your `.zshrc`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3483679/7190191).

Comment: Probably the issue is with oh-my-zsh. Here is a gif to reproduce - https://gifyu.com/image/bYA3. `ctrl-u` deleted the complete line.

Comment: Great! This helped!

Comment: I use zsh (without oh-my-zsh), and I can confirm `ctrl-u` deletes the whole line.