# Zsh: Ctrl+C to delete current line without creating new prompt

Tags: zsh, zsh-zle

So I really like `ipython`'s feature where it deletes the current line when you press Ctrl+C *without* creating a new prompt below. Is it in any way possible to do this in Zsh? I have tried the obvious (`bindkey -M [desired_mode] '^C' kill-whole-line`) but it didn't seem to work, and [elsewhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289300/how-to-map-ctrl-c-to-normal-mode-in-zle#comment505889_289300) I found advice to *not* remap Ctrl+C, so I was wondering if anyone knows a solution to this problem. :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete from current position to the beginning of the line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44846908/how-to-delete-from-current-position-to-the-beginning-of-the-line)

Comment: Try a Ctrl+U. Should be by default bound to `kill-whole-line`. At least it works for me.

Comment: Well my question more about remapping `ctrl+c` specifically to save me muscle memory that might not be applicable in places in ipython, but ok :-)

Comment: I don't know ipython well, but may you can remap the keys for ipython, so that this one also understands ctrl-u?